# API Mercadopago: Como generar un nuevo Token de Pago, luego de un "payment" rechazado

Tags: javascript, mercadopago

Probando en entorno Sandbox, tengo una app que genera un "token de pago", que luego envío al servidor para generar el "payment".
El escenario es durante la prueba de mensajes de error:

1. pruebo fondos insuficientes, agrego FUND delante del nombre
2. recibo el error correspondiente, hasta aquí todo correcto.
3. cambio para probar expiración, agrego EXPI delante del nombre.
4. me da error 400, bad_request, mensaje de error completo: 
   *"could not update the Cardtoken with the following id: b67f82b44375001c136081b3b392f1f7 because has been used or expired"*

Entiendo que el token solo puede utilizarse una vez y aparentemente la API lo quiere actualizar, cuando en realidad debe generar uno nuevo.

Alguna idea de que debo estar haciendo mal?

Comment: Estas usando javascript en el frontend, o quieres hacer los pagos desde backend usando nodejs ?

Comment: Si, para el frontend estoy usando el SDK de javascript, y para el server implementé el SDK PHP.  Funciona todo bien, excepto cuando un pago es rechazado y por si solo no puedo volver a intentar el mismo pago, ni siquiera utilizando otros datos de tarjeta. Solo pude hacerlo funcionar llamando a clearSession() luego de un pago rechazado.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

La documentación de Mercadopago es incompleta y no muy clara.

Pero revisando la clase Mercadopago del SDK de javascript, se puede ver un prototype llamado clearSession(), que efectivamente hace lo esperado.

[image: Mercadopago prototypes]

```js
// limpiar sesion, luego de "payment" rechazado
Mercadopago.clearSession();

// validar que el usuario no utilice los mismos datos rechazados.
validarForm();

// generar nuevo token luego de pago rechazado
Mercadopago.createToken(form, callback);

// procesar nuevamente el pago
crearPago();
```

Comment: Buen trabajo de investigación y encontrando la solución a tu problema. No te olvides de marcar esta respuesta como aceptada. Saludos.

Comment: Casi dos años después sigo funcionando tu solución jaja, muchas gracias guillefd

Comment: genial! gracias por avisar, sigo pensando si es así como se hace, la nueva documentación https://www.mercadopago.com.ar/developers/es/plugins_sdks/sdks/official/js/  sigue sin mencionar nada sobre clearSession() o por lo menos no lo encuentro.